# Checksum for a 32-bit integer

Tags: checksum, 8051

I'm trying to figure out how to do a checksum for a 32-bit integer (4 bytes).

It should reliably detect error in the number, and be as easy to compute as possible.

Ideas:

```
(bytes: a,b,c,d)

cksum = (((a xor b) xor c) xor d)
cksum = (((a / b) / c) / d)
```

Will this work for a simple checking, or should I try to implement something more "mainstream" like adler or crc? I just need to check if the number is OK, not to fix errors in it or anything like that. Ideally the checksum is 8 bits long.

I'm implementing this in assembly on 8051

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "reliably detect" and post that.  What's the possibility of a multiple bit error changing one valid set of data to another valid set of data - for example, a simple parity bit can't detect if two bits are in error.

Comment: I basically have to check if there's the right value I've written before, or some garbage. I suppose just writing a "mark" byte would do, but it's not the best idea probably (it's flash memory, so I don't think it'll randomly go corrupt)

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: I quite obviously no longer need the answer, but if you're in for the points, you can have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard checksum works like this:

- Add all the data bytes and drop down the carry,
- Take the 2’s complement of total sum.

To verify the checksum add all the data bytes including the checksum. If the result is not zero then some data have been corrupted.

In C, you can do

```
unsigned char checksum(unsigned char data[]){
    unsigned char sum = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; sizeof(data); i++){
        sum += data[i];
    }
    return ~sum + 1;
}
```